# How do I declare a variable inside an if else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var user = prompt("what is your name?");
if (user == "joe")  {
  var game = "what's up joe"
}
if (user == "alex") {
  var game = "hello alex how are you"
}
else {
  game = "sorry don't know you"
}

var other = alert(game);
```

For some reason this does not work I want to make game be equal to a number of different things. If I use more than 3 if statements game is always equal to the last one. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Declare "game" outside the if statement an use it inside.

```
var user = prompt("what is your         name?");
var game = "";
if (user == "joe")  {
  game = "what's up joe"
} else if (user == "alex") {
  game = "hello alex how are you"
} else {
  game = "sorry don't know you"
}

var other = alert(game);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't: [No such thing as block scope in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

And probably the best article on the topic: [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var user = prompt("What is your Name?");
var auth = "joe";
if (user == auth) {
  alert("Whats Up ")+ user;
};
else if(user != auth | user!=="alex"){
  alert("I dont Know you! ")+ user;
};
else {
  alert("Error!");
};
```